# error on multi select

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am getting the following error when try to save.

```
SQL Query: INSERT INTO `table`.`users` (`username`, `password`, `group_id`, `applications`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES ('asdasd', '23ad37a839e26fc46a1f6640861a47305aea5d46', 3, Array, '2012-04-03 02:12:19', '2012-04-03 02:12:19')
```

here is the code for multiple select

```
echo $this->Form->input('User.applications',array('options'=>$options,'multiple'=>'multiple'));
```

and the add method is called, which is:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                                //debug($this->request);exit;   
                                $this->User->create();
                                if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                                } else {
                                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                                }
                            }
                            $groups = $this->User->Group->find('list');
                            $this->set(compact('groups'));
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it using this

```
public function add() {
                            if ($this->request->is('post')) {

                                if(count($this->request->data['User']['applications'])){
                                    $this->request->data['User']['applications'] = implode(",", $this->request->data['User']['applications']);
                                }
                ....
```

Comment: That works, but keep in mind it will be hard to search or join on that column. Ideally you should be using a separate table and model to manage multiple applications per user.